# How do I run multiple dotnet commands?

Tags: ubuntu

I have recently installed the .Net core framework 2.2 from Microsoft's website on my Ubuntu server.

Whenever you run the `dotnet [.dll file]` it will have a prompt saying:

> Application running on port 3030
>
> Press Ctrl+C to close server

I was wondering how would I be able to run more than one .Net Core application. It seems I can SSH the server again and load up another application. That will load both applications at once.

Is there a way where I can bypass the keyboard lock when it only lets me to press Ctrl+C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can suspend the application with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.  Once suspended, resume the application in the background with the `bg` command, or you can bring it back to the foreground again with the `fg` command. If you background the application and run more applications afterwards, you can find the job number of your application with the `jobs` command after which you can use `fg <job number>` to bring it to the foreground before stopping it with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

---

A better approach is to create a Systemd unit file which allows you to stop and start the service at your leisure or on boot.  Run `sudo systemctl edit --force myFirstDotNetService.service`.  In the editor, add the following:

```
[Unit]
Description= My First Dot Net Service

[Service]
ExecStart = /path/to/dotnet /path/to/dll-file

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

There are [many more options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#) you can add to this file, but the above should get you started.

Next, let the server know about this new file with: `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.

You can now start the service with: `sudo systemctl start myFirstDotNetService` and stop it with `sudo systemctl stop myFirstDotNetService`.  When you start, the application is placed in the background and the command prompt returns.

You can make it automatically start at boot with: `sudo systemctl enable myFirstDotNetService` and stop this with `sudo systemctl disable myFirstDotNetService`.